# Are "Find a product with the same feature" questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I found myself potentially needing an Event Streaming product.  Everything I read talks about Kafka (and only Kafka).  I have yet to hear of another viable alternative that uses an *persistent continuous commit log* (which my research shows is the core of Event Streaming).

I would like to know if there are other tools out there that also have a persistent continuous commit log for event streaming.  It seems like a question with discreet answers to ask for a list of Event Streaming products that have a persistent continuous commit log.  (I don't care which ones are "best", just looking for a list.  I will decide which ones are best for my company.)

But it smells like a product recommendation question.

**So I thought I would ask here if such a question would be considered off topic or not?**

Comment: Enumerating all possible products that fit a criteria is only going to be complete at one point in time. Tomorrow, two more can appear. In a year, five from the old list might be dead or renamed or similarly not available.